# How to make a glowing neon perspective grid in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, grids, perspective

I’ve been experimenting in GIMP; I didn’t get on so well with Inkscape.
I want to get into retro designs in an 80's style. I found [this old (closed) question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/77527/19174) with an 80's text made in GIMP but the *grid* and *perspective* tools are still a mystery to me.

I want to make a blue neon grid like in the following pic:

[image]

On my computer I just see the grid as white lines that I can adjust but only as “information” and not as an object with color like in the picture with blue squared lines.

Comment: I edited information from the comments into the question. It would still benefit from further elaborations on what you tried and failed. I leave it to the community to decide whether it wants to reopen the question in its current state.

Comment: Have you tried using Filters > Render > Pattern > Grid, and then use the Perspective Tool on the Grid?

Comment: My corner of the community thinks the question is answerable as it is.

Comment: Hey Guys!! Thank u so much for the answers! I played along with it and finally I got my crid to be in those colors I wanted but still it's really messy. I'll attach a picture as soon as I can. The lines/squares seem to be very messy. I'll re-do some things and get back! All the best!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want it sharper than in the example. So start with the wanted resolution. Here is taken 1600 x 1200.

The bottom layer is the background. The lower half is a blue-black gradient. The upper half is here only black:

[image]

The next layer is the grid. If you want it single color, you can now select the wanted color. You can change the color later easily. I made it cyan. The grid is drawn by filter Render > Pattern > Grid:

[image]

Unfortunately GIMP does not show the result fullscreen as you set the filter. Maybe in the future versions. But the filter works anyway and there came out a fullscreen grid.

The line widths are 4 pix. Horizontal lines shrink 50% when the perspective is applied. They stay thick, if you make them wider, for ex. 6 pixels.

The perspective tool was used. The top of the grid was pulled down to the center of the image and the bottom corners were pulled to far left and right.

[image]

If you want the grid to mix to blue at the middle of the image, you can add a coloring layer. Alternatively you can add a layer mask that fades the grid. Here is cyan to blue gradient for coloring. It's blending mode is "Color".  The opacity controls the depth of the effect:

[image]

The coloring affects also to the non-black part of the background. That can make the result richer. The following is the same with a layer mask, which is more controllable, but also maybe more clinical:

[image]

Comment: Man!!!! This is TOTALLY AWESOME! Totally answered! 
I can't wait to come home and try this!!! Don't know what to say, it's awesome! I will try to also make it more "flatly" and "upfront" like this one: 
https://blog.fotolia.com/us/files/2016/05/Fotolia_93198683_S_copyright.jpg
 I have a guess that I can achieve that by lowering the top horizontal line of the grid and by that it will look like the surface/level looks more "wider" and deeper,don't you think? 


anyways THANK U SO MUCH!

Comment: @DeeKey Right! The perspective is pulled more down  from the top and the foreground is wider.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong haha but cannot make it to work. Will try harder. But just wanted to ask if there's a chance that you can make a YT tutorial or smthn - if you do that on another channel or so already? :) Otherwise I'll just try harder. Can try PM'ing you and explain where it messes up!

Comment: @DeeKey I have no good enough tools for making screen videos that use continuous colors. I can record screen actions that are BW or have a few discrete colors only => no tutorial videos. You can open a chat where you show different phases of your trial. Have you the background ok?