# How to make grid canvas

Tags: grids, canvas

[image]

The picture will be crop one by one and make into a canvas

Comment: It just looks like 4 prints, what do you need to know? The software part or the print itself? What software are you going to use? Can you [edit] to make clear what exactly you need help with? Also check [ask] and note that this is not a tutorial-on-demand site.

Comment: In your example one can see a faint pattern which resembles a perspective grid. Is it the actual goal for this question? Programs have grid generating functions and perspective transformations. With them you can make decorative grids. The thing has been discussed in older cases like this  https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/96021/how-to-make-a-glowing-neon-perspective-grid-in-gimp

Answer (score 2):

1. Add some guides to an image for cropping, using the raster image editing software of your choice.
2. Crop and export one piece using the guides you previously made.
3. Undo the crop and repeat step 2 until all pieces have been done.

Example

[image]