# Minor GIMP help

Tags: gimp

I'm making a custom poster for a Plex film collection in Gimp by loosy following this tutorial:

[How to make retro 80's chrome text in GIMP?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77527/how-to-make-retro-80s-chrome-text-in-gimp)

...but he said to do something that doesn't exist in gimp:

> Text Shading:
>
> 1. Create 2 new transparent value layers (Layer>New Layer or button in layers list) above each of the main text layers. Change the layer mode
>    from "Normal" to "Value" for each.

The thing is, is that there is no "Value" layer mode at all.

Comment: There's mode group switch in the layers panel in the same line as the current mode is shown. Click it to get extended selection available. But in GIMP 2.10 both sets have mode Value, so the problem is a mystery. I guess you have the extended set in use, but forgot to scroll down enough in the list.

Comment: I did not forget to scroll down to see it, there is no "value" mode, all the layer modes are easily visible and I only have to scroll down to see a couple more when I try to make a new layer. I'm using the newest version of gimp and everything.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you linked to is over 5 years old. GIMP had a major update from version 2.8 to 2.10 in 2018, with many changes, and there have been many updates since. Currently at version 2.10.24 as of today's date.

In one of those updates (can't remember which specifically) the name of the "Value" layer mode was changed to "HSV Value". It's near the bottom of the list. I'm not entirely sure if it's a direct equivalent to the old 2.8 layer mode. Try it and see.

If it doesn't work as expected, try the Legacy layer modes available in the drop down in the layers panel. It's now called "HSV Value (I)".

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. It's a very vague tutorial, so I'll probably be back with other questions.

Comment: @ThatFetcherFargoth - You're welcome. Note that it's often hard to unpick someone else's tutorial, especially when they're for older versions of GIMP.  You might be better to look up some more modern tutorials. There are lots on youtube. But I'm glad to help if I can.

Comment: @ThatFetcherFargoth - oh forgot to say, Welcome to GDSE!!  I've given you some upvotes to help with your rep score.  Keep contributing and asking!!

Comment: Thank you very much